# cakephp 1.3 ajax with jquery

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3.

I want to use its Ajax helper and the [CakePHP 1.3 AJAX documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/AJAX.html) says that I will have to use `prototype.js` and `scriptaculous.js` to work with it.

But I am already using jQuery for my project and it conflicts with the `prototype.js` file.

So is there any way to work with **Ajax helper and jQuery** instead of Ajax helper and prototype / scriptaculous?
(I don't want to use prototype.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided:

> Both the JavascriptHelper and the AjaxHelper are deprecated, and the
>   JsHelper + HtmlHelper should be used in their place. See The Migration
>   Guide

On [Js helper page](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Js.html):

> Since the beginning CakePHP's support for Javascript has been with
>   Prototype/Scriptaculous. While we still think these are an excellent
>   Javascript library, the community has been asking for support for
>   other libraries. Rather than drop Prototype in favour of another
>   Javascript library. **We created an Adapter based helper**, and included 3
>   of the most requested libraries. Prototype/Scriptaculous,
>   Mootools/Mootools-more, and **jQuery**/jQuery UI. And while the API is not
>   as expansive as the previous AjaxHelper we feel that the adapter based
>   solution allows for a more extensible solution giving developers the
>   power and flexibility they need to address their specific application
>   needs.

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); // Include jQuery library
```

And also take a look at the [jQuery AJAX pagination example](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Js.html#ajax-pagination).

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from the red box at the top of that page:

> Both the JavascriptHelper and the AjaxHelper are deprecated, and the JsHelper + HtmlHelper should be used in their place.

Have a look at the documentation for the [JsHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Js.html) instead.